# Remote Desktop Access to Local Networked Machine

Tags: network, remote-desktop

If an attacker had access to another system on my home network, how could I protect myself while still having access to the internet? What steps or things could I do to increase the **security on my side** to protect myself?

In this scenario I cannot interfere with the compromised machine (this is a theoretical situation, realistically I could disinfect the other machine, but **I want to know what I could do on my end**).

Comment: Setup a [dmz](http://superuser.com/questions/301298/would-you-setup-a-dmz-at-home).

Answer (score 1):

All machines on an untrusted or semi-trusted network should run their own firewalls. They should also be running anti-virus and have strong pass phrases for all logins and no default ID's. You should also make sure that remote support & remote access protocols are turned off unless needed. Periodic anti-rootkit and anti-malware checks may also be helpful. In other words, all the usual stuff you would do. Laptops should also have fully encrypted drives and ideally disabled USB ports (though few people will want to live with the hassle of that).

You haven't said what OS but assuming Windows 10, it already has a reasonable, pre-configured firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Julian's post, if you're using an ISP supplied WiFi router, that'll provide you with a little more protection.

The vast majority of routers these days have built-in firewalls that are enabled by default. This isn't adequate protection on its own though.